# How to copy form fields with PdfWriter not PdfCopy in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I would like to merge two PDF files (only selected pages) and add custom headers and footers to them.

Therefore I do not use `PdfCopy` that simply copies the page without altering it.
I use the `PdfWriter`.

The problem is I do not know how to copy AcroFields, Acroforms, Annotations and everything else except content with the `PdfWriter`.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Since you mention you want only specific pages of a pdf, take a look at the "GetPageContent()" method in the PdfReader class. One of the overloaded prototypes simply takes a page number, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `GetImportedPage` method of the `PdfWriter` class. This copies everything into a `PdfImportedPage` that you can then use.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(originalFile);
PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNumber);
```

As an example, you can place the previous code in the `OnOpenDocument` event of a `PdfPageEventHelper` and then in the `OnEndPage` event you can use the `DirectContentUnder` object of the `PdfWriter` to place the entire page underneath your current page.

```
pdfWriter.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
```